# ReactJS - onDragEnd called endlessly on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I am trying to handle the `onDragEnd` event, triggered when an image is dragged and then dropped. On Firefox, The event is triggered on drop, but not only once, it's raised endlessy.

Relevant part of code:

```
  {['350x150', '350x250', '150x150'].map(size => {
    return (
      <img key={size} src={`https://via.placeholder.com/${size}`}
        onDragEnd={() => alert(1)} 
       />
    )
  })}
```

Full reproduction of problem: https://codepen.io/vmarquet/pen/qJaOmJ?editors=0010 (open with Firefox, just drag one of the placeholder images to trigger infinite alert popups).

Am I misusing React's `onDragEnd`? If not, is this a ReactJS known bug or a Firefox known bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeout for example

```
 {['350x150', '350x250', '150x150'].map(size => {
    return (
      <img key={size} src={`https://via.placeholder.com/${size}`}
        onDragEnd={() => setTimeout(()=>{alert(1)}, 0)}  
       />
    )
  })}
```